# Python - How to convert list back into it's original dataframe after using .apply(pd.eval) function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I have a panda dataframe (defined in my code as 'df1') where the data are text but I want them converted to integers/numbers. I have years (row/left column) and word descriptions (column) as my dataframe indices. Example below

```
     |Alpha   |Bravo   |Charlie |Delta  |   
2020 |1.98M   | -7.40M |0.00    |29.55K |
2021 |-5.30K  | 23.2B  |-       |35.01K |
```

I applied below code to clean the data above to ensure values can be recognised as integers rather than text:

```
repl_dict = {'−':'-', '—':'','[kK]': '*1e3', '[mM]': '*1e6', '[bB]': '*1e9'}
df2 = df1.replace(repl_dict, regex=True).apply(pd.eval)
print(df2)
```

The above code manages to convert my values to integers, however the .apply(pd.eval) function also reformats my dataframe by re-transposing, making each row of values back into a list, and my years disappear, and the list goes into one column. Example of output:

```
       |0                        |
Alpha  |[1980000, -5300]         |
Bravo  |[-74000000, 23200000000] |
Charlie|[0.00, 0.00]             |
Delta  |[29550, 35010]           |
```

Please can someone help, I have been unable to find a solution to make this work? I do not need to use .apply(pd.eval) function if there's another method to achieve the below output

Desired Output:

```
     |Alpha     |Bravo         |Charlie |Delta  |   
2020 |1980000   | -7400000     |0.00    |29550  |
2021 |-5300     | 23200000000  |-       |35010  |
```

Many thanks in advance!

Also tried:

```
.apply(pd.eval, axis=0, result_type = 'broadcast')
```

Returns "ValueError: cannot broadcast result"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'normal' eval, not 'pd.eval', combined with stack/unstack:

```
df1.stack().replace(repl_dict, regex=True).apply(eval).unstack()
```

output:

```
        Alpha        Bravo          Charlie Delta
2020    1980000.0   -7.400000e+06   0.0     29550.0
2021    -5300.0      2.320000e+10   NaN     35010.0
```

Note I had to tweak you `repl_dict` for this to work, but this may not be quite the right thing for you depending on how you construct your `df1`, the white spaces etc so you may have to experiment a bit:

```
repl_dict = {'−':'-', '-$':'None','[kK]': '*1e3', '[mM]': '*1e6', '[bB]': '*1e9'}
```